# solution communication between two windows

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have two tkinter windows. A button should be in the first window, and a reaction text should be in the second window.
My questions:

1. Must the second window have no modal?
2. How do I make the second window movable?
3. How can I give information to second window via callback function?

Thanks in advance for answers and advice!

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? Try something first, show the code, then ask for help.

Comment: This question shows no effort in doing any research. There are lots of questions and tutorials and documentation that show how to create multiple windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that may help you:

```py
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window1 = Tk()
        self.window2 = Toplevel()

        self.button = Button(self.window1, bd = 5, text = "Click Me!", command = self.update)
        self.button.pack()

        self.label = Label(self.window2, bd = 5, text = "Button has not been clicked.")
        self.label.pack()

    def update(self):
        self.label.config(text = "Button has been clicked!")
        self.window2.update()
app = App()
```

Explanation:

The first line imports tkinter

In the next line, we create a class. At the bottom of the code, we create an object using that class. This is useful because when the object is created, the functions in the class are already defined, so the function definition can be after when it is called.

After we declare our class, in `__init__`, we write code that will run when an object is created from that class. The code creates two windows. One contains a button, and the other one contains a label. The button has a command parameter to run the class function, `update`.

In update, we change the label text and update the window.

Comment: You  should almost never create two instances of `Tk`.  Why do you think that's a better solution than using `Toplevel` for the second window?

Comment: @BryanOakley I fixed the button issue. Please don't downvote me (if you were the one who did). I don't have much reputation to begin with. It is also unnecessary since the code works.

Comment: If you're going to provide an answer that creates two instances of `Tk`, you need to explain why that's superior to using an instance of `Toplevel`. Creating more than once instance is bad advice to give someone who likely doesn't understand the consequences.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have changed the `Tk` to `Toplevel`. Again, if you downvoted me, the answer is fixed (unless you have any issues still). I don't have much reputation, and if the downvote stays there, I have lost ~10% of my reputation.

Comment: Thanks you for your advices and interst about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have not next questions. My problems solution is here:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ViewOnMoon(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent = None, draw = None):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.transient(parent)  

        self.title('View')
        self.minsize(height = 300, width = 300)

        fr_canvas = tk.Frame(self)
        fr_canvas.place(relx=0.23, rely=0.01, anchor="nw")

        self.canv_w = 200
        self.canv_h = 200
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(fr_canvas, bg='white', width = self.canv_w, height=self.canv_h)
        self.canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        return

class GuiMoonMove(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        mon_h = 600
        mon_w = 1250

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master, width=1000, height=200, bd=2)

        self.master.title('Move')
        self.master.minsize(height = mon_h, width = mon_w)

        fr_canvas = tk.Frame(self.master)
        fr_canvas.place(relx=0.23, rely=0.01, anchor="nw")


        fr_button = tk.Frame(self.master)
        fr_button.place(relx=0.02, rely=0.06, anchor="nw")

        self.canv_h = 600
        self.canv_w = 950

        self.lbl_view = tk.BooleanVar()  

        chb_view_on_moon = tk.Checkbutton(fr_button, text="Pohled na Měsíc", variable = self.lbl_view, \
            onvalue=True, offvalue=False,command = self.callback)
        chb_view_on_moon.grid(column= 0, row= 4,pady = 10)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(fr_canvas, bg='white', width = self.canv_w, height=self.canv_h)
        self.canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

    def callback(self,*args):
        if self.lbl_view.get()==True: 

            self.view_on_moon = ViewOnMoon(parent = self.master)
        else:
            self.vom.destroy()

if __name__=="__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    app = GuiMoonMove(master = root)
    app.mainloop()
```